# Understanding choice of $\lambda$ in proof of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality relying on the observation $0\le (x-\lambda y|x-\lambda y)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

In [Luenberger book](http://books.google.com/books?id=lZU0CAH4RccC&pg=PA47) Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality is defined like this: For all $x,y$ in an inner product space $|(x|y)| \le \|x\|\|y\|$. Equality holds if and only if $x = \lambda y$ or $y = \theta$.

Proof starts for all scalars $\lambda$,

$$
0 \le (x-\lambda y | x-\lambda y) = 
(x|x) - \lambda(y|x) -
\bar{\lambda}(x|y) + |\lambda|^2 (y|y)
$$

I understand this expansion. But then, it will select a particular $\lambda  = (x|y)/(y|y)$, and obtains

$$
0 \le (x|x)  - \frac{|(x|y)|^2}{(y|y)}
$$

I dont understand how he chose that particular $\lambda$. I guess I understand why, he chose it to get rid of it in the main equation, but is it okay to chose any $\lambda$ that will clean up the equation like this?

Comment: I find the notation in this question a bit hard to read. (Indeed, I think it has induced some typos.) Is that the notation from the source you cite? Using $|$ both as a separator in the notation for an inner product and for the standard modulus $|\cdot|$ makes things more difficult to parse than need be. I would suggest either $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ or, if you insist on parentheses, $(\cdot,\cdot)$. Cheers.

Comment: @cardinal It seems that the author of the book really uses this notation, see the Google Books preview: http://books.google.com/books?id=lZU0CAH4RccC&pg=PA47

Comment: @Martin: (+1) Yikes.

Comment: Is the condition for _equality_ to hold stated correctly in Luenberger's book? What the OP has posted above is what is in the book in a chapter titled Hilbert Space, but it is in a section titled Pre-Hilbert Spaces.  I believe that in Hilbert space, $x$ need not **equal** $\lambda y$ for equality to hold but rather only the _slightly weaker_ condition $||x - \lambda y|| = 0$ is needed. But perhaps the condition is intended for spaces in which $||z||=0$ exactly when $z$ is identically $0$, and the more general version is proved later. I don't have the book, only the couple of pages in the link.

Comment: Aimed at physics students, I guess, where $(x|y)$ or $\langle x | y \rangle$ is the standard.

Comment: About the Luenberger notation: yes, that threw me off a bit too, but that's how he uses it, not sure why.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: you are right that the condition for equality (linear dependence) rests on nondegeneracy. But the only difference between Hilbert and Pre-Hilbert spaces is completeness. By definition both are equipped with an inner product, i.e. a *nondegenerate* positive symmetric bi(/sesqui-)linear form.

Comment: In my opinion, anybody interested in Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in general, and the question asked here in particular, should read and ponder [this page](http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/csineq.html) by Tim Gowers on the subject. Those interested in going further might want to have a look (and probably, much more than a look) at the gem of a book titled [The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class: An Introduction to the Art of Mathematical Inequalities](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Publications/Books/CSMC/CSMC_index.html) by J. Michael Steele.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I dont understand how he chose that particular $\lambda$. I guess I understand why, he chose it to get rid of it in the main equation, but is it okay to chose any $\lambda$ that will clean up the equation like this?

Yes, the inequality that you display holds for all $\lambda$ and so "it is okay
to choose any $\lambda$" that you like.  Luenberger's choice (it might well be the
one used originally by Cauchy and/or Schwarz) "cleans up the equation" as you
note, and provides motivation for its use.  But if you have another value for
$\lambda$ in mind that allows you to reach the conclusion
$$0 \le (x|x)  - \frac{|(x|y)|^2}{(y|y)},$$
(which is just a re-arrangement of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality), by all means, go for it.

See Appendix B of this [Lecture Note](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece361/spring11/NewLectures/Lecture03.pdf) for a more prolix proof of 
the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality than the one in the Luenberger book.

Answer (score 3):

As said before, we always have $$0\leq\|x-\lambda y\|^2=(x-\lambda y|x-\lambda y)$$
Of course the choice $\lambda=\frac{(x|y)}{\|y\|^2}$ is neither arbitrary or accidental luck. Geometrically the specific   $\lambda$ chosen is the one that gives the *orthogonal projection of $x$ along the vector $y$*.

The product $(x|y)$ removes the part of $x$ that is orthogonal to $y$, and dividing by $\|y\|^2$ normalizes $y$.

Consider the picture below where

- the black arrow is to picture $x$
- the blue arrow is to picture $y$
- the red arrow is to picture $\lambda y$
- the green arrow is to picture $x-\lambda y$

[image: OrthogonalProjOfXontoY]

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yes, of course. Thanks Jonas :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong idea. Actually, you don't need to select $\lambda$. For every $\lambda$,

$0 \le (x-\lambda y | x-\lambda y)$, that means

$0 \le  (x|x)-\lambda(y|x)-\bar{\lambda}(x|y) + |\lambda|^2 (y|y)$,Consider it a function with the independent variable $\lambda$. So if $\lambda$ is R

$\Delta= 4(x|y)^2-4(x|x)(y|y) \le 0$. If $\lambda is C$, you need to use other functions.